# How to set windows console buffer size use golang?

Tags: windows, go, console

I'm code a project , but the windows console buffer size is not enough to dispaly the data . how to fix it ?

I'm try to do this:

```
cmd:=exec.Command("cmd", "-c", "mode con cols=100 lines=500")
```

but it not work .

Comment: Windows 10 provides a console API which can probably do what you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/

Comment: I find the API but always get incorrect parameters , i don't know how to use , i code like this :  `type coord struct {
 x, y int16
}

func resizeConsoleBuffer() {
 kernel32 := syscall.NewLazyDLL("kernel32.dll")
 proc := kernel32.NewProc("SetConsoleScreenBufferSize")
 c := &coord{x:int16(100), y:int16(500)}
 proc.Call(uintptr(syscall.Stdout), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(c)))
}`@JimB